# How to run a .Net Core application with the FullTrustLauncher from UWP?

Tags: uwp, .net-core, windows-10-iot-core, desktop-bridge, windows-iot-core-10

We have a UWP apllication which needs to start a win32 exe. I'm currently writing a .net core application which will do that job. The problem now is, how do I start this dll from the UWP application. With a normal exe I know how to do it, but how does it work with this dll.
We are using .net core because we need to support Windows 10 Iot Core.

How do I start a .Net Core dll from UWP using the FullTrustProcessLauncher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FullTrustProcessLauncher works for EXEs that are included in your package. If you want to run a .net core app you will need to first publish it as a self-contained EXE, as described here, then you can launch it via FullTrustProcessLauncher:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#self-contained-deployment

Also note that FullTrustProcessLauncher is not supported on Windows IoT Core. However, you can use ProcessLauncher there to accomplish the same:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.ProcessLauncher

Since ProcessLauncher isn't strictly limited to EXEs from your package (you can whitelist allowed EXEs in the registry), you may actually be able to accomplish your scenario without putting a .net core app in the middle in Windows IoT Core.

Comment: This is not the answer I wished to get, but at least I know now that it won't work

Comment: How did you read from my answer that it won't work? It will work if you compile the .net core app as an EXE and use ProcessLauncher on Windows IoT Core. Also you may not even need a .net core app on IoT as you could whitelist the Win32 EXE you want to call and then launch it directly with ProcessLauncher.

Comment: Yeah thats what I understood :), I just meant that I hoped there was a way without packing as a selfcontained exe, because it generates a lot of dll files which I would also need to include in my UWP application. Thanks for the tip with win32 exe